# How to change the (no title) text in a list

Tags: column

Does anyone have an easy way to change the text that appears in a list when the Title field is left blank?

At the moment it is the ootb (no title) and is linked to the item information, but I would like it to show a different text without actually populating the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually rename Title field using SharePoint designer, so may be this renamed field will be useful for you. Another way is to make some kind of autofilling, there is multiple ways to do that:

- Write Adding, Updating Event Receivers and populate some values to the Title field.
- Add JavaScript to Add, Edit forms, and during presaveAction() function set some values to the Title. You can hide Title from forms also by JavaScript.

I prefer rename Title, so I can use it for other purposes, because this field has few useful functions, it has context menu in views by default, also it has link to view form by default.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I don't want to add a value to the field, I want to leave it empty and I want to keep the column as a title field as it is later populated downstream by a workflow. I just want to change the text that is displayed while it is empty, just as you might change the text on the 'add new item' button but those tricks don't seem to work here. I appreciate your response.

Comment: So, any list view is xslt list view web part, you can customize xslt for this web part using SharePoint Designer, so visually on the current list view Title will be the link,  contains text you want

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about changing the default text when empty title...

But usually for this either I update the New Item form and hide the title field and set it using JavaScript to the text I want to appear...

Or totally hide the Title field from forms, list views by List Settings -> Allow management of content types -> click Title -> Hidden

I would suggest wait for other people to answer :)

Comment: I am sure that your way is the easy way to go, unfortunately I have a workflow set up that relies on the field being empty, which I could change but that has knock on effects. Might not even be possible to do it the way I'd like, but I thought it was worth asking :) Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to do this. First, make sure you have jquery loaded on the page (either in a MasterPage, Script Editor, etc).  Then add:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeNoTitle(){
            $('[field="LinkTitle"] a:contains("No Title")').html("*Substitute Text*");
        }
        _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("changeNoTitle");
    </script>
```

To a script editor web part.

Also, if you are on a list view page and can't otherwise open the page for editing, add "ToolPaneView=2" as a url parameter to the page and refresh.  E.G.:

https://sharepoint.mycompany.com/Lists/ExampleList/AllItems.aspx?ToolPaneView=2

or

https://sharepoint.mycompany.com/Lists/ExampleList/AllItems.aspx?OtherUrlParam=OtherUrlParamValue&ToolPaneView=2

This will force a page into edit mode.